# Background-image not showing

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I am trying to turn images that appear on the site using the  tag into a background image. MY first code looked like this

Html:

```
<img class= "house" src="images/House-03.png" width="122px" height="118px"/>
```

CSS

```
.house {
display:block;
position:absolute;
float:right;
bottom:0;
right:0;
```

}

Now I'm trying to change it like this:

Html

```
<p class= "house"> </p>
```

CSS

```
.house {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(../images/House-03.png);
    width:122px;
    height:148px;
    float:right;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Except the image doesn't appear! Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Remove the space before the "house". You don't need to float an absolute positioned element.

Comment: Your code is ok just check image URL

Comment: Can we see your website tree to be sure your image url is correct ?

Comment: for absolutely positioned element do we really need float:right ? and p is by default block element so no need of display:block as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try setting the background image size property

```
.house {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background:url(../images/House-03.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width:122px;
    height:148px;
    float:right;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

hope this helps?

Answer (score 3):

put quotes around your image url

```
background-image:url("../images/House-03.png");
```

ETA : per comment below... quotes are indeed not required! just mentioned it here to troubleshoot the original question.

Comment: oops I put the quotes in my  code I just forgot to put them in my question.

Comment: o yes, if you want the background to show fully, you need to set the background-image size, as rand0m says above.

Comment: Quotes are not necessary

Answer (score 3):

I personally had the pathname and url syntax correct. The only issue was

```
background-img: url("")
```

needing to be changed to..

```
background: url("")
```

And my background pattern revealed itself triumphantly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your image is accessible!

After a lot of frustration, it turned out that my problem had to do with the image not being accessible... You can always test out your code with another image on another site that is certainly accessible...

Answer (score 0):

As shown by other answers there can be many things that can prevent a background from showing. So even though the question is "Why is the image not showing?" a more general question is "How can I find out why my CSS-rule doesn't seem to take effect?"

I had the same or similar problem about background image not showing up and was able to find the answer by adding the "!important" -qualifier to my CSS-rule. That made the image appear, which made me realize there must be some other CSS-rules with higher priority that prevent this particular rule about background from taking effect.

That is a good trouble-shooting tip in general. If some CSS-rule doesn't seem to have any effect, try adding "!important" to it, and see if that helps. If so, look for other rules that are preventing your rule from taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting one of the leading dots (../). I had this exact same problem thinking two dots is the previous directory but it's actually two back.